# Display chinese characters in console application

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mfc, console-application

I have the following console app in Visual Studio

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wcout << "displayStringsTest_data" << endl;
    wcout << L"列举" << endl;
    wcout << "Done" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But the Chinese characters are output as question marks

Does anyone know how I can get them output in the correct form

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/388500)

Answer (score -1):

Even though you are sending correct Chinese symbols to console.

Windows setting should be changed so that it supports those language specific characters.

You need to change PC language to Chinese from "Region and Language" section from control panel, which is by default to US English.